# Change default editor for .cpp files

Tags: gedit, c++, default, r

When I double click .cpp files I expect gedit to open it, instead RStudio opens it. How to set gedit as the default editor for .cpp files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Ubuntu 14.04, all you need to do is, as above, right-click, open with, other application..., and just select the program. If the program is not listed, press the button labeled "Show other applications" and choose from there.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on a .cpp file and go to properties. In "Open With" tab select gedit from the list and below the list select "set as default".